# HTTP Error 310 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with RequireHttpsAttribute ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, https, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building an application on ASP.NET core using MVC. I'm also using the Identity and Entity 7 framework in my application.
I'm running the application on Microsoft Azure which should come with a HTTPS certificate.

I'm enabling HTTPS in my Startup.cs using this code

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            #if !DEBUG
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            #endif
        });
```

My problem is that when I visit the web app I get a 310 HTTP ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS response. I already tried to clear my cookies and re-publish the web app to Azure but none of these work out.

When I disable the above code my application works on Azure. When I then manually type https:// in the browser I get a secure HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem with my applicaton.

Please check your `Startup.cs` `Configure` method. In there you should have included `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();`.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    .....

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    .....
}
```

The RequireHttpsAttribute uses this IISPlatformHandler for enabling HTTPS on your website.

Comment: this is for asp.net core rc1 not rc2

Comment: The question doesn't specify, but I *think* given the date that the question was asked that it might be about RC2 rather than RC1. I have had the same problem in RC2 but rather than confuse things and since there is an answer here for RC1 I've asked the question specifically about RC2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954796/requirehttpsattribute-with-netcore-rc2-causes-http302-redirect-loop-on-azure?noredirect=1#comment63383388_37954796