# RequireHttpsAttribute with ASP.NET Core MVC - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC website on a IIS Windows 2016 Server.

In my `startup.cs` file I have tried to configure automatic redirection to **https** if user is on **http**. 
However, Chrome (and other browsers as well) keeps telling me:

```
This page isn’t working
www.example.org redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies. (yup, did that)
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

1. I followed this guide to enforce https:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl
2. I have properly installed an SSL cert. from letsencrypt.org
3. I have followed this guide to use IIS instead of Kestrel:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

This is my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...   
    // Enforce https
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    // Enforce https
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
         .AddRedirectToHttps();
     app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

If I turn off the `RequireHttpsAttribute` I can browse the website without any problems. 
I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019631/560784 which says include the following in `startup.cs`. Did not work either :(

```
  services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
  {
       options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
   });
```

Hoping for some help - what am I missing?

Comment: This is the first time I see `app.UseRewriter(options);` for enforcing HTTPS in ASP.NET Core. From my experience, using only the `RequireHttpsAttribute` as you do in `ConfigureServices` is enough

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to the first link I posted, the `RequireHttpsAttribute` ignores all **http** traffic requests, which is why (to my understanding) the `app.UseRewriter(options);` is required later on, which makes sure to redirect **http** traffic to **https**. But maybe I am wrong?

Comment: From the beginning of the first link: "`RequireHttpsAttribute` uses HTTP status codes to redirect browsers from HTTP to HTTPS"

Comment: From the mod (Nbarbettini) on that link "The filter and the redirect do separate things: The filter prevents ASP.NET Core from responding to HTTP requests (hence RequireHttpsAttribute). The redirect will automatically rewrite any incoming request with http to https."
- I have removed `app.UseRewriter(option)` to see what happens, problem persists. Scratching my head.

Comment: The filter and the rewriter do practically the same thing, but they apply at different layers. The filter only applies to mvc, where the rewriter applies to all requests that get that far in the pipeline. If you have the rewriter then you don't need the filter.

Comment: Most likely your x-forwarded-proto header is messed up. Is your server behind any kind of load balancer? Can you write a middleware to log the request headers and share them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tratcher. I have removed `...= ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;`- there is no load balancer, just a clean IIS. Not sure how to write that middleware to log the request but I be happy to test.

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/810c4bcb0a29fb5f273a0c2b26b37e4ee431d05c/samples/IISSample/Startup.cs#L32

Answer (score 1):

As per comment from Microsoft personnel on the [Enforce HTTPS in an ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio) thread on Microsoft Documentation:

"You need to apply [AllowAnonymous] to the login if you're using templates created before 2.1"

Comment: I have not yet had the time to dive more into this but I am not using login functionality, so that is not the culprit I believe.